# encryption sdk with asymmetric KMS key

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kms, encryption-asymmetric

Is it possible to use AWS Encryption SDK in a networkless environment, if I am using an asymetric AWS-KMS key, and provide the public key to encrypt the data-key with?

Theoretically, it should be possible, but my question is whether AWS Encryption SDK supports it